# How get time series data or stats of VBR bitrates?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

Given a file or stream of audio encoded as VBR (Variable Bit Rate), how could one measure (list or statistically summarise) the bitrate variations over a time period?

(Independently of whatever may be stated in metadata)